# How to fetch only image from a content

Tags: php

Hi! I have a content like

```
<p>
    <a href="http://haha.yellowandred.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/535540_273587499393207_2112055176_n.jpg">
        <img class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-9" title="Reasons heals nothing" src="http://haha.yellowandred.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/535540_273587499393207_2112055176_n-212x300.jpg" alt="" width="212" height="300" />
    </a>
</p> 
<p>
    The post <a href="http://haha.yellowandred.in/reasons-heals-nothing/">Reasons heals nothing</a> appeared first on <a href="http://haha.yellowandred.in">haha</a>.
</p>
```

From this content I have to fetch only image tag and its properties.

How can I this?

I used `preg_match()` but I can't do what I need so could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

This should start you upon the right path. Don't use regex unless absolutely necessary.

[**SimpleHtml DOM Parser**](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery is another way to go if you're up for it

```
$(document).ready(){

var src = $('p a').find('img').attr('src');
var title = $('p a').find('img').attr('title');
var classname = $('p a').find('img').attr('class');

alert('Title:'+title+'\n'+'Source:'+src+'\n'+'Class:'+classname);

});
```